# How to set language in Biber (1.6)?

Tags: languages, biber, polyglossia

I am using `biber` to manage my bibliography. I am using MikTeX with all updates installed. After updating to 1.6 however, my language settings don't work. Despite setting `German` as prime language, the bibliography gets outputed in English. What changed? Or what did I do wrong.

Here is the MWE:

```
% test.tex

% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding =UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headings=small]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}


\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear-icomp,
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bibliographie.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Einleitung}
Ich möchte \textcite{bannas2012} zitieren und bin gespannt auf das Ergebnis.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

With `bibliography.bib`:

```
% Encoding: UTF8

@ARTICLE{bannas2012,
  author = {Bannas, Günter},
  title = {Angela Merkel in Indonesien},
  year = {2012},
  month = jul,
  url = {http://www.faz.net},
  urldate = {2013-03-21},
}
```

Maybe, language related `biber`s log helps:

```
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'bibliographie.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'de_DE.UTF-8' default tailoring 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Sorting 'entry' list 'nyt' keys
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'de_DE.UTF-8'
INFO - Writing 'einstellungen.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
```

Comment: See: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/121

Comment: Okay, so this is a `Polyglossia` problem. How can I use `Biblatex` 2.7 dev? Where to extract to install it on MikTeX?

Comment: You can download the dev-branch here: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/tree/dev -- However it's important to setup `biblatex.sty` to the current date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `biblatex` core team knows the issue and provided a fixed in the current `dev` branch at github.

[PLK wrote at github](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/121):

> This is due to a change in Polyglossia >1.2 which can't be patched in the same way as before. Biblatex 2.7 dev version on SF fixes this.

The dev branch can be downloaded here: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/tree/dev

Comment: If you check the latex run log, you'll see an error about not being able to patch `babel` - that's the problem which requires the `biblatex` 2.7 update. `polyglossia` defines an identical macro to `babel` for compatibility and it's this macro which changed in `polyglossia` 1.3.

Comment: @Marco Daniel, thanks! I switched back to `babel` as I did not succeed with installing manually now. Will try again later or wait for the official release and update via MikTeX.